# Vue.js component parent event

Tags: javascript, html, events, vue.js, components

im wondering why my code isn't working. I have an event 'leave' which should be called on blur. The components are displayed properly but when i leave the inputs the event wont be triggered.

```js
Vue.component('text-input', {
  props:['args'],
  template: '<input :id="args.id" :type="args.type"/>'
})

App = new Vue({
  el : '#app',
  data: {
   inputs : [
    { id : 'nickname', type : 'text'},
    { id : 'email' , type:'email'}, 
   ]
  },
  methods : {
   leave : function(event) {
    
   var id = $(event.target).attr('id');
    console.log('left object ' + id);
   }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id='app'>
  <div class="form-group">
    <text-input 
      class="form-control"
      v-for="input in inputs"
      v-bind:args="input"
      v-bind:key="input.id"
      v-model="input.id"
      v-on:blur="leave"
      />
  </div>
</div>
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `v-on:emit` sets an event handler (`leave()`) for the `emit` event. Is the `text-input` component emitting an `emit` event?

Comment: @tony19 Sorry, i meant blur instead of emit. I edited the code above. Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `<text-input>` component needs to forward (re-[emit](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-emit)) the `blur` event from the inner `<input>` element:

```
// text-input
template: `<input @blur="$emit('blur')">`
```

Then, `<text-input>`'s parent could receive it:

```
// parent of text-input
<text-input @blur="leave" />
```

```js
Vue.component('text-input', {
        props:['args'],
        template: `<input :id="args.id" :type="args.type" @blur="$emit('blur', $event)"/>`
})

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      inputs: [
        {id: 1},
        {id: 2},
      ] 
    }
  },
  methods: {
    leave(e) {
      console.log('leave', e.target.id)
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@2.5.16"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div class="form-group">
    <text-input 
      class="form-control"
      v-for="input in inputs"
      v-bind:args="input"
      v-bind:key="input.id"
      v-model="input.id"
      v-on:blur="leave"
      />
  </div>
</div>
```