# Vue.JS: Why won't parent element receive event? Does parent have to be a custom component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

I am noob to Vue.js.  I thought the Events made sense: I assumed they bubbled up through the DOM tree until caught by a parent.  But I must be missing something.  The following code doesn't work, doesn't generate any errors or warnings, and in the Vue developer tools, I see the event being emitted.  What am I missing?

index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/vuex@3.1.2/dist/vuex.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

    <div id="app" @button-clicky="gotevent">
        <div @button-clicky="gotevent">
            <h1>{{ info }} {{ counter }}</h1>
            <button-component />
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="./main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js:

```
Vue.component('button-component', {
    data: function() {
        return {
            count: 1
        }
    },

    methods:
    {
        clicky() {
            this.$data.count++;
            this.$emit('button-clicky');
        }
    },

    template: `<button @click="clicky">Go {{ count }}</button>`
});

const vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        info: "this is title.",
        counter: 0
    },

    methods: {
        gotevent() { 
            this.$data.counter++;
            alert('The event was heard!'); }
    }
});
```

Can't I listen for an event on any parent level above the component emitting it?

I added the listener on both the direct parent `<div>` and also the 'app' container, but nothing happens and no errors or warnings are thrown.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Vue events bubble like DOM ones, you need to catch them on the emitting component, so `<button-component  @button-clicky="gotevent" />`

Comment: So you're saying events can't bubble pas the actual component, and must be forwarded at the component level (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419311/vue-js-component-parent-event) to reach the parent?  What about event bus: https://alligator.io/vuejs/global-event-bus/  I can't get that to work either, but is that the required method for "global" events?  That's such an ugly solution to something that *could* have been so elegant.

Comment: This guy has an event bubbling directive (https://gist.github.com/loilo/597fa84f4d7e6b7552373f2df9517b45), which its really just a shorthand way of making your events bubble - you would still need to add it all the way up through your component chain. I would say keep plugging away at the EventBus if you really need global events.

Comment: @RyanGriggs The Vuex store is generally considered preferable to using an event bus. As for component event bubbling, I know it seems like a good idea but in practice it would cause more problems than it solves. As an example, consider how `v-model` is implemented and how bubbling component `input` events would affect that.

Comment: So even changing it to `<button-component @button-clicky="$emit('button-clicky')">` doesn't allow me to catch the event with the parent <div>.  Am I missing something?  I can see the events being emitted in Vue dev tools.